# Is there a way to run a ci that is not in master

Tags: circleci

As the title suggests, is there an option of running a CI before it is merged to master?
There are some features that I would like to test with some repos without merging my CI to master.

Similar to github actions where you can choose which from branch to take the CI if you are running it manually

Comment: CircleCI doesn't only run on the default branch, so it's not clear why you think you need any special option for this. What does your current config look like?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Was my bad, had an issue with naming, made it seem as if it wasn't seeing a job that wasn't merged to master. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does so by default, was my issue with naming.